# python matplotlib rounding date

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been trying to make a plot that has date as the x-axis using matplotlib.

However, when i use the code, it seems that it decides to not show the year if there are less than 6 entries in the plot. Example 5 entries:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
Dates = ['2018/04/01', '2018/04/02', '2018/04/03', '2018/04/04', '2018/04/05']
y = [10, 20, 30, 56, 42]

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for date in Dates]
plt.xticks(rotation = 20)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

The output is this:

[image]

What i want is for that output(5 entries) to have the same x axis format output as if i had 6 entries. Example of a desired plot:

[image]

I would guess that my problem has to do with rounding, but i couldn't find any solutions that worked in my case.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `plt.set_xticks()`

Comment: I already tried this earlier, with fig,     ax = plt.subplots() and then 
    ax.set_xticks(x), but it only made 2018 be the only x-axis info.

Comment: Sorry, put `ax.set_xlim()` instead.

Comment: How about `plt.plot(Dates,y)`?

Comment: Thanks, @Zhiya! I never considered doing something "easy", since none of the tutorials ever did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) to format the dates, and [`set_ticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticks.html) to set the tick mark locations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

Dates = ['2018/04/01', '2018/04/02', '2018/04/03', '2018/04/04', '2018/04/05']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for date in Dates]
y = [10, 20, 30, 56, 42]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

# set the location of the tick marks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x)

# format the tick labels
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]